# How to override table data using Hibernate for specific criteria using hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate

We are generating Sales Report using Hibernate.

**Scenario**

When user clicks on generate report button after entering some criteria, I am fetching data from database using hibernate, then we are doing some data manipulation to generate actual report data. Report data is stored in ArrayList, which then persisted into database in CommissionSummary table, which is mapped with hibernate entity as below

**CommussionSummary.java**

```
@Column(length=100)
private String advisorName;
private String advisorCodeParent;
@Column(length=100)
private String advisorNameParent;
@Column(length=100)
private String advisorPost;
@Column
private Double percentage;
@Column
private Double diffPercentage;
@Column
private Double saleAmount;
@Column
private Long saleCount;
@Column
private Double commissionAmount;
@Column
private Integer month;
@Column
private Integer year;
```

Report is generated for every month. 
My Question is: For 05 July 2012 user has generated data so i am storing this information in CommissionSummary table. Now user has generating the same report on 15 July 2012, then it should override earlier month data.

**Override criteria should be month and year.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is a simple data checking.
Solution One:
1. Load data from DB and check those data for possible duplication.
2. If you find them equal, delete the older version.
Solution Two:
One other possible solution is to define your columns **unique**, so if a user wants to put the same data, he will be receiving some exceptions. Something like this:

```
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"advisorName", "advisorNameParent", "advisorPost", "percentage", "diffPercentage" , "saleAmount", "saleCount", "commissionAmount" })

@Column(name = "ADVISOR_NAME", length=100)
private String advisorName;
private String advisorCodeParent;
@Column(name = "ADVISOR_PARENT_NAME", length=100)
private String advisorNameParent;
@Column(name = "ADVISOR_POST" , length=100)
private String advisorPost;
@Column(name = "PERCENTAGE")
private Double percentage;
@Column (name = "DIFF_PERCENTAGE")
private Double diffPercentage;
@Column (name = "SALE_AMOUNT")
private Double saleAmount;
@Column (name = "SALE_COUNT")
private Long saleCount;
@Column (name = "COMMISSION_AMOUNT")
private Double commissionAmount;
```

Using this, you can check if there were some errors you can do your desired action.

Comment: I want to do almost similar thing as you said above, but if data already there then update that with new amount values. But solutions, I will prefer using hibernate annotations. UniqueConstraint will throw an error, which i think is not better approach.

Comment: I have tried overrding equals method for (advisorCode, month, year) uniqueness. and then using getSession().saveOrUpdate(commissionSummary).

Comment: I cannot see which properties identify that these two data are the same? Have you tried to use unique constraint on them? BTW, I see no advisorCode in the written code in your question.

Comment: Yes I tried usign UniqueConstraint (advisorParentCode,month,year) it gives the exception, which can I can catch and update record. Does it can be done with the help of overriding equals() and using saveOrUpdate() method

Comment: Simply use saveOrUpdate() when exception arises. Catch it and update your record. I don't see any advantages in overriding equals().

Answer (score 0):

Get the CommissionSummary for the given month an year using a HQL query:

```
select c from CommissionSummary where c.year = :year and c.month = :month
```

If not null, delete it:

```
session.delete(existingCommissionSummary);
```

Then save the new one.

Comment: Do not want to check using manual query. Using Hibernate Annotation is what i will prefer.

Comment: Good luck finding this magical annotation that will do that for you. It doesn't exist. This is functional code that you have to write.